# Count consecutive values in row > 0 being able to control how many values in a row (2 - 3 or more..) and then SUM it

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm kind of stuck with this I hope you could help me.

What I want is to:

-SUM but only when there are values in consecutive cells greater than zero.

-I would also like to identify and command the function to Sum only when there are two consecutive values and so on, it doesn't matter if I have to enter a different function per column but to know if the sum is the result of 2, 3 or more consecutive cells.

- It can get more problematic if there are more than one series of consecutive values per row, but at least I would like to be able to solve in the case of existing simple intervals with isolated values like the example in the image above.

I guess it would be something with SUMIF but I can't get the criteria for what I want to do.

[here is a link of a google sheet file with data and expected results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CKnEHNQ6qdZODGe21qAvLKR2EF-uCq9z1iqh_d4brlQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[just the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsgHN.png)

Answer (score 1):

*What you are trying can be achieved by using Helper Data along with COUNTIF:*

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- To count consecutive values, an array (CSE) Formula in cell AE3, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  ```
  {=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF($R3:$Z3>0,ROW($R3:$Z3)),IF($R3:$Z3<=0,ROW($R3:$Z3))))}
  ```
- Enter Helper data in AA1:AD1 as shown in screen shot.
- Formula in cell AA3, fill it across.

  `=IF(COUNTIF($R3:$Z3,">0")=AA$1,SUM($R3:$Z3),0)`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*